# What is the relation between carrier signal and local oscillator in RF system?

Tags: rf, wifi

I have a confusion between the carrier signal and the local oscillator and based on my understanding, IQ signal (data) is mixed with carrier signal to become a modulated RF signal and before transmission, it has to be mixed with local oscillator frequency to become IF frequency for transmission.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

The carrier signal is a base signal with a known frequency/phase. It is modified by the input signal to represent the information.

The carrier can be modified in amplitude (AM, amplitude modulation), frequency (FM), or phase (PM). This are the classical, 20th century approaches.

However, the energy spent in the carrier is not useful itself, so it is considered a waste of transmitting power. Therefore modern modulation methods like SSB (single side modulation) the carriert itself is suppressed and has to be added at the receiver by a BFO (Beat Frequency oscilator).

WiFi can be modulated either by:

- 802.11b (<=11 Mbps): Quadrature Phase Shift Keying (QPSK)
- 802.11a and g (<=54 Mbps): Binary Phase Shift Keying (BPSK), Quadrature Phase Shift Keying (QPSK), or one of two levels of Quadrature Amplitude Modulation (16, or 64-QAM).

Comment: Hi @Sanjo, thanks for the comment. Is the local oscillator used to generate the carrier signal?

Comment: @KokCheowYeoh No. The local oscillator is used by the receiver to bring down the received signal to a lower frequency which can be more easily processed via the heterodyne principle.